# Display JSON response using PHP from URL

Tags: php, json

I have a feed from a parcel tracking service that i am trying to integrate into my site. I have a url which allows me to put the tracking number at the end and get a json response. I have multiple objects from this which include some static info such as the senders address and some info which I will need to use a foreach for like the tracking progress.

I believe I have got the string okay however I am not sure how I am meant to display the info.

This is what I have so far:

Example URL:

> domain.com/REST_Service/webservice/consignee/SelfshipService.svc/web/Tracking/84941354665

URL Returns:

```
{
  "Agent": null,
  "Consignee": {
    "Address1": "25 HEATHFIELD ROAD",
    "Address2": "SHOLING",
    "Address3": "",
    "Code": null,
    "Company": "ERIK HANSON",
    "Country": "GREAT BRITAIN",
    "Dept": "",
    "Email": "ERIK.HANSON66@GOOGLEMAIL.COM",
    "Name": "",
    "Phone": "07770320490",
    "Postcode": "SO19 1DL",
    "State": "HANTS",
    "Town": "SOUTHAMPTON"
  },
  "CrossIdx": "",
  "Error": null,
  "NonDel": null,
  "POD": {
    "Date": "13 Jul 2016",
    "Status": "Harnett",
    "Time": "09:17"
  },
  "Pieces": 1,
  "PosErr": 0,
  "Tracks": [
    {
      "Date": "13 Jul 2016",
      "Status": "Out for delivery",
      "Time": "07:10"
    },
    {
      "Date": "13 Jul 2016",
      "Status": "At Delivery location Portsmouth",
      "Time": "02:24"
    },
    {
      "Date": "13 Jul 2016",
      "Status": "At Delivery location Portsmouth",
      "Time": "02:22"
    },
    {
      "Date": "12 Jul 2016",
      "Status": "Arrived At Ryton",
      "Time": "22:12"
    },
    {
      "Date": "12 Jul 2016",
      "Status": "Preparing for despatch",
      "Time": "14:00"
    },
    {
      "Date": "12 Jul 2016",
      "Status": "Scanned into OCS HEATHROW LONDON",
      "Time": "13:59"
    },
    {
      "Date": "12 Jul 2016",
      "Status": "Consignment details verified",
      "Time": "13:59"
    },
    {
      "Date": "14 Jun 2016",
      "Status": "Shipment prepared by customer",
      "Time": "11:20"
    },
    {
      "Date": "02 Jan 2003",
      "Status": "Collected from Customer",
      "Time": "09:32"
    }
  ],
  "Weight": 7
}
```

Current PHP:

```
//set tracking url
$url = "http://www.ocscourier.co.uk/REST_Service/webservice/consignee/SelfshipService.svc/web/Tracking/84941354665";

// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.ocscourier.co.uk/REST_Service/webservice/consignee/SelfshipService.svc/web/Tracking/84941354665");

//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

//call api
//$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($output);
$Address1 = $json->results[0]->Consignee->Address1;
$Address2 = $json->results[0]->Consignee->Address2;
echo "Address 1: " . $Address1 . ", Address 2: " . $Address2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `json` string doesn't have any `results` key (so I'm not sure why you trying to access `results[0]`.

You can just use

```
$Address1 = $json->Consignee->Address1;
$Address2 = $json->Consignee->Address2;
```

Check this code:

```
$s = <<< END
{
  "Agent": null,
  "Consignee": {
    "Address1": "25 HEATHFIELD ROAD",
    "Address2": "SHOLING",
    "Address3": "",
    "Code": null,
    "Company": "ERIK HANSON",
    "Country": "GREAT BRITAIN",
    "Dept": "",
    "Email": "ERIK.HANSON66@GOOGLEMAIL.COM",
    "Name": "",
    "Phone": "07770320490",
    "Postcode": "SO19 1DL",
    "State": "HANTS",
    "Town": "SOUTHAMPTON"
  },
  "CrossIdx": "",
  "Error": null,
  "NonDel": null,
  "POD": {
    "Date": "13 Jul 2016",
    "Status": "Harnett",
    "Time": "09:17"
  },
  "Pieces": 1,
  "PosErr": 0,
  "Tracks": [
    {
      "Date": "13 Jul 2016",
      "Status": "Out for delivery",
      "Time": "07:10"
    },
    {
      "Date": "13 Jul 2016",
      "Status": "At Delivery location Portsmouth",
      "Time": "02:24"
    },
    {
      "Date": "13 Jul 2016",
      "Status": "At Delivery location Portsmouth",
      "Time": "02:22"
    },
    {
      "Date": "12 Jul 2016",
      "Status": "Arrived At Ryton",
      "Time": "22:12"
    },
    {
      "Date": "12 Jul 2016",
      "Status": "Preparing for despatch",
      "Time": "14:00"
    },
    {
      "Date": "12 Jul 2016",
      "Status": "Scanned into OCS HEATHROW LONDON",
      "Time": "13:59"
    },
    {
      "Date": "12 Jul 2016",
      "Status": "Consignment details verified",
      "Time": "13:59"
    },
    {
      "Date": "14 Jun 2016",
      "Status": "Shipment prepared by customer",
      "Time": "11:20"
    },
    {
      "Date": "02 Jan 2003",
      "Status": "Collected from Customer",
      "Time": "09:32"
    }
  ],
  "Weight": 7
}
END;

$json = json_decode($s);
$Address1 = $json->Consignee->Address1;
$Address2 = $json->Consignee->Address2;
echo "Address 1: " . $Address1 . ", Address 2: " . $Address2;
```

Here is the output:

```
Address 1: 25 HEATHFIELD ROAD, Address 2: SHOLING
```

Comment: When accessing it as per your example I am still getting an error. 

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in parcel-tracking.php on line 29

Comment: Maybe your string is not what you added in the example? If you run the exact code in my answer it works (check here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cab3a789c3dfaa70e11e8032e3b37bd3c91df64b)

Comment: This is my full code: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8b97b4a00708d7ddbfa1c0352ddd1e3d1829a997

If you go to the URL you will see the output

Comment: The problem is with the URL. Did you check it (in your browser)? :)

Comment: Please double check. Copy & Paste the **exact** URL from the code you posted :)

Comment: Ahh yes I missed the https:// so I have changed it from http:// to https:// and I still get the same notice/error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126217/discussion-between-ben-h-and-dekel).

Answer (score 0):

**Below is json string in $json variable and access with RecursiveIteratorIterator**

***Example***

```
$json='{
  "Agent": null,
  "Consignee": {
    "Address1": "25 HEATHFIELD ROAD",
    "Address2": "SHOLING",
    "Address3": "",
    "Code": null,
    "Company": "ERIK HANSON",
    "Country": "GREAT BRITAIN",
    "Dept": "",
    "Email": "ERIK.HANSON66@GOOGLEMAIL.COM",
    "Name": "",
    "Phone": "07770320490",
    "Postcode": "SO19 1DL",
    "State": "HANTS",
    "Town": "SOUTHAMPTON"
  },
  "CrossIdx": "",
  "Error": null,
  "NonDel": null,
  "POD": {
    "Date": "13 Jul 2016",
    "Status": "Harnett",
    "Time": "09:17"
  },
  "Pieces": 1,
  "PosErr": 0,
  "Tracks": [
    {
      "Date": "13 Jul 2016",
      "Status": "Out for delivery",
      "Time": "07:10"
    },
    {
      "Date": "13 Jul 2016",
      "Status": "At Delivery location Portsmouth",
      "Time": "02:24"
    },
    {
      "Date": "13 Jul 2016",
      "Status": "At Delivery location Portsmouth",
      "Time": "02:22"
    },
    {
      "Date": "12 Jul 2016",
      "Status": "Arrived At Ryton",
      "Time": "22:12"
    },
    {
      "Date": "12 Jul 2016",
      "Status": "Preparing for despatch",
      "Time": "14:00"
    },
    {
      "Date": "12 Jul 2016",
      "Status": "Scanned into OCS HEATHROW LONDON",
      "Time": "13:59"
    },
    {
      "Date": "12 Jul 2016",
      "Status": "Consignment details verified",
      "Time": "13:59"
    },
    {
      "Date": "14 Jun 2016",
      "Status": "Shipment prepared by customer",
      "Time": "11:20"
    },
    {
      "Date": "02 Jan 2003",
      "Status": "Collected from Customer",
      "Time": "09:32"
    }
  ],
  "Weight": 7
}';
 $jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
 new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),
 RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
        echo "$key:\n</br>";
    } else {
        echo "$key => $val\n";
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
    Agent => Consignee:
Address1 => 25 HEATHFIELD ROAD Address2 => SHOLING Address3 => Code => Company => ERIK HANSON Country => GREAT BRITAIN Dept => Email => ERIK.HANSON66@GOOGLEMAIL.COM Name => Phone => 07770320490 Postcode => SO19 1DL State => HANTS Town => SOUTHAMPTON CrossIdx => Error => NonDel => POD:
Date => 13 Jul 2016 Status => Harnett Time => 09:17 Pieces => 1 PosErr => 0 Tracks:
0:
Date => 13 Jul 2016 Status => Out for delivery Time => 07:10 1:
Date => 13 Jul 2016 Status => At Delivery location Portsmouth Time => 02:24 2:
Date => 13 Jul 2016 Status => At Delivery location Portsmouth Time => 02:22 3:
Date => 12 Jul 2016 Status => Arrived At Ryton Time => 22:12 4:
Date => 12 Jul 2016 Status => Preparing for despatch Time => 14:00 5:
Date => 12 Jul 2016 Status => Scanned into OCS HEATHROW LONDON Time => 13:59 6:
Date => 12 Jul 2016 Status => Consignment details verified Time => 13:59 7:
Date => 14 Jun 2016 Status => Shipment prepared by customer Time => 11:20 8:
Date => 02 Jan 2003 Status => Collected from Customer Time => 09:32 Weight => 7
```